# Why my disk elevator is set to "deadline"

Tags: linux, centos, performance, hard-drive, scheduler

I have CentOS 6.x Linux server with kernel `2.6.32-573.8.1.el6.x86_64`.

I did some checks today and I found that disk elevator is "deadline".

```
[root@srv ~]# cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler 
noop anticipatory [deadline] cfq
```

I have almost same server, but installed 4 mo ago. it is with kernel `2.6.32-573.3.1.el6.x86_64`. It's scheduler is "cfq" as expected.

Is there some changes in the kernel, or just my hosting company did it?

I also can not find where this is set - `/etc/sysctl.conf` is stock.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to set on the kernel command line with e.g. `elevator=deadline`. I don't know for sure, but I consider it very unlikely that the default changed between 573.3.1 and 573.8.1 of Red Hat's 2.6.32 kernel.

You can inspect your kernel command line by reading `/proc/cmdline`.